# How should I go about animating a background gradient according to a value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, gradient

So I am creating a widget for streamlabs, currently I am trying to figure out how to animate the css "background: linear-gradient(#cf8888 -5%, #df4747 100%);" according to the % of the height from this div. The javascript already controls the height of the div according to the "goals" current.

Any suggestions where I should start to animate this BG?

IE example:

```
<div class="goal-start"></div>

#goal-start{
  position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(#cf8888 -5%, #df4747 100%);
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
```

Comment: Created sample fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshnayak/q6j5axcf/

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.goal-start{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab );
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    -webkit-animation: gradientBG 10s ease infinite;
            animation: gradientBG 10s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes gradientBG {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
@keyframes gradientBG {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="goal-start"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I can alternate this code to trigger when the % of the height increases.